# Shortcut to create C++ class method?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have class definition code with function to be crated name

```
class CAAA
{
public:
    public_method
}
```

I expect to create function stub in header and .cpp with help of some shortcut.

Trying to create class method in fast way:

Shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> brings `No suggestions available`:

[image]

Shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> brings `No Default proposal`:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Upvote, because image was necessary to explaine...but anyway, what do you expect? I think you define a class, but the suggestions are empty because there is not method available so far...

Comment: Which suggestions do you expect ?

Comment: @YSC It's not an image of code, it's an image of an IDE's pop-up window. The image is 100% appropriate here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the available methods are found by parsing the class definitions; and not the functions you've written randomly which it can't guess should belong to a class or namespace.

Comment: @Angew my bad then. I cannot see images from imgur, I assumed it was code. (a)OP: could you add a text description?

Comment: I have added more details in question body

Comment: For methods like `foo();` in the header file, _Source > Implement Method..._ creates the method stub in the source file. By default, this function has no shortcut, but you can add one in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_.